# Jmeter: Generating aggregate report through commnd line is not including 95% and 99% line in generated report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter 2.13. We are generating the aggregate report **through command line**

`java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv aggregate.csv --input-jtl merged.csv --plugin-type  AggregateReport`

When the aggregate report is generated through Jmeter UI i am getting the 95% and 99% line.

Answer (score 3):

In the `/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin` folder, the `jmeter.properties` files states as follows:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Aggregate Report and Aggregate Graph - configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Percentiles to display in reports
# Can be float value between 0 and 100
# First percentile to display, defaults to 90%
# aggregate_rpt_pct1=90
# Second percentile to display, defaults to 95%
# aggregate_rpt_pct2=95
# Second percentile to display, defaults to 99%
# aggregate_rpt_pct3=99
```

Copy this to `user.properties` file and uncomment the `aggregate_rpt_pct1=90`to get 90th percentile in the generated `Aggregate Report`.

You can add e.g `aggregate_rpt_pct3=70` to get the 70th percentile in the generated Aggregate Report.

Comment: We have tried the same but its not working. Still 95 and 99 percentile are not coming.