# How to print 95 and 99 Percentiles in the jmeter aggregate report command line?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, percentile

I am trying to print 95 Percentile and 99 Percentile response times in the jmeter aggregate report from the command line
For this, I have tried the solution mentioned in here: [Jmeter: Generating aggregate report through commnd line is not including 95% and 99% line in generated report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659023/jmeter-generating-aggregate-report-through-commnd-line-is-not-including-95-and) 
but that didn't work. I have tried editing the `jmeter.properties` file too.
Also, the other solution that I came across is to generate the `ResponseTimesPercentiles` graph using `CMDRunner.jar` in csv format but that gives all the values from `0-99.9` which I don't need. So is there a way I can customize the csv file to just have `ReponseTimesPercentiles` for **desired values**?

Also tried this command:

`java -jarCMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl results.jtl --include-labels aggregate_report_99%_line --plugin-type AggregateReport`

which didn't work.
So, is there any way that I can generate the 95% and 99 Percentiles in the **aggregate report**

Answer (score 8):

The functionality is available **by default** starting from [JMeter version 2.13](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-know-about-jmeter-213)

[image: JMeter 90, 95, 99 percentiles]

The behavior is controllable via the following properties:

```
aggregate_rpt_pct1=90
aggregate_rpt_pct2=95
aggregate_rpt_pct3=99
```

If you don't see percentiles like at the above image in your [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) - add the above lines to *user.properties* file.

NB:

- The approach won't work on JMeter versions earlier than 2.13
- JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up, dynamic changes won't work.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T
I am able to view those percentiles in the GUI mode but I want to print them when I generate the aggregate report from the command line

Comment: @user6348718 did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it from CMD, First make the plan using GUI, then in the bin folder of Jmeter, open CMD and run the following command.

```
jmeter -n -t "[PATH-FOR-PLAN]\myplan.jmx" -l "[PATH-OF-RESULT]\results.csv" -e -o "[PATH-OF-OUTPUT]\output"
```

The output folder will have a webpage with the `aggregate report`

Comment: I dont see the -e option is version 2.13. pls mention your jmeter version

Comment: it requires lots of memory, for my tests involving > 40k the file isn't generated anymore. I allocated 25G to java but still getting a heap space exception. This solution does not scale.